# Is it possible to have more than 5 read replicas in Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

The [Amazon RDS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/) seems to suggest that you can't have more than 5 replicas. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Amazon only allows you to create up to 5 replicas, and need to be launched one by one.

If You need more than 5 you can create a Master-slave configuration using EC instances, then you can have as many replicas as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is a workaround that allows to have more than 5 read replicas - by creating read replicas of existing read replicas. It's still up to 5 read replicas per DB, and up to 2 layers (so max 30 read replicas in total).

To enable read replica to have read replicas, automated backups must be turned on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Five read replica's are more than enough for most of the times. More than 5 can impact the performance.

Scale up technique:
if you are using m1.xlarge, you can scale up to Quadrapule EXL and get better performance with 5 RR itslef.

If your system demands more than 5 you can solve this by refining your architecture in following ways:

P1) Functionally partition the DB and have read replica's accordingly

P2) Offload read traffic to Amazon ElastiCache and DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

One flavor of RDS Engine type - Aurora (for MySQL / PostgreSQL) supports up to 15 read replicas 
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html

Answer (score 0):

10 years later, RDS limits can be lifted. Look for "Yes" in the "Adjustable" column:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.Limits

The usual caveats apply for measuring performance impact of additional replicas on the primary.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Amazon RDS for MySQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL allow you to add up to 15 read replicas to each DB Instance." under Setup section in [RDS feature](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/)!

Answer (score 0):

This has now changed, the current status (2023, November) is according to [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/):

> Amazon RDS for **MySQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL** allow you to add up to **15**
> read replicas to each DB Instance.

> Amazon RDS for **Oracle and SQL
> Server** allow you to add up to **5** read replicas to each DB Instance.

Answer (score 0):

yes in latest release you can create upto 15 read replica.

[https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/#:~:text=Use%20the%20%22Create%20Read%20Replica,replicas%20to%20each%20DB%20Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20%22Create%20Read%20Replica,replicas%20to%20each%20DB%20Instance).